# Is there a tool to analyse a J2SE app's portability to Android?

Tags: java, android, portability

I'm looking for an easy way to identify potential issues when porting a J2SE app to Android without having to go through line by line. Ideally I'd like a tool that would flag SE classes and members for which there is no Android equivalent, but if not, a crude library level flag would be sufficient.

If there's no tool, is there a J2SE library to Android library mapping somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reference the Android library and nothing else and see what breaks at compile time.

Best of luck. It might not be pretty.